# Go to previous activity after finish

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two screen , Screen A and Screen B

I open Screen B in A as below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this , B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity B I have two cases.

First case user will press on back button. He will successfully go back to screen A.

Second case after some network operation I need to go back to screen A so i do it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this , A.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

The problem is there will be two screen of A in stack 
so first it open A screen then if user click back it will also show screen A 
in the third attempt he will go back to the other screen , say screen C

Comment: Please explain better your problem, in particular these lines: "*The problem is there will be two screen of A in stack so first it open A screen then if user click back it will also show screen A in the third attempt he will go back to the other screen , say screen C*".
You talked about two screens (A and B) at the beginning and at the end you nominated a third, my brain is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create another instance of Activity A? Calling `finish()` in Activity B will take you back to the next Activity on the stack anyway, which will be the original instance of Activity A.
If you need, following the network operation, to return some result to Activity A, then you should explore using the `startActivityForResult()` method in Activity A when launching Activity B.